# Debugging why file isn't displaying UTF-8 characters

Tags: php, file-io, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

For some reason, special characters are not displaying on my website. My site is full of `â†’â€œâ€œ` and so on.

My HTML header has

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

My htaccess file has

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

I've tested the website on http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php and it correctly returns

```
Content-Type => text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The [CMS I'm using](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile) uses PHP, does not use a database, and includes

```
('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

The website uses markdown (.md) files, but I don't know why that would be causing the problem? **What else can I do to debug/fix this problem?**

Comment: _“The website uses markdown (.md) files”_ – and those have been saved in what encoding?

Comment: @CBroe stupid question, but I have no idea how to tell/specify. I simply hit "new file" in Brackets and saved it as .md.

Comment: @CBroe I've been searching for how to save a .MD as UTF-8 and haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Is Brackets part of your CMS?

Comment: @CBroe nope, its just what i'm using to edit files http://brackets.io/

Comment: Try a text editor that explicitly allows you to specify the encoding to use when saving a file (such as NotePad++ for windows.)

Comment: @CBroe I opened the .md files up in Notepad++ and clicked on "encoding" and it was marked as UTF-8 already.

Comment: @CBroe just discovered the culprit was a plugin, and not in fact my fault for saving something the wrong way :) -- thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the problem was a plugin I had installed and not an issue with my HTML/htaccess/files. Always make sure to check if a 3rd party is messing you up. The code I cited in the question should be all that is needed to ensure UTF-8 is rendering unless you've got plugins/scripts that interfere with theme initialization.